# Optimization over Spectral Laplacian in cycles and trees

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, graph-theory, mathematical-modeling, linear-algebra

Is there any idea on how one can deal with an optimization problem of sum of k largest eigenvalues(min) of Laplacian matrix of a simple cycle or tree?
I would like to use semidefinite programming for modeling as it's mentioned in [Alizadeh's](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0805002) paper.

Thanks for your comments in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question. The sum of the eigenvalues of the Laplacian of a graph with m edges is always 2m. So what exactly are you trying to optimize?

Comment: @Casteels: You're right. I edit my question.

Comment: So, for example, for fixed $n$, you want to characterize the trees on $n$ vertices whose sum of first $k$ eigenvalues is maximum? 

Comment: @Casteels: yes, that's what I want to do. I am trying to start from a simple cycle and with knowing symmetric properties expand my work to trees and some other class of graphs.